# Find the subspace formed by intersection of given subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We are given three subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$W_1 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid a_1=3a_2\space$and$\space a_3=-a_2\}$

$W_2 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid 2a_1-7a_2+a_3=0\}$

$W_3 = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid a_1-4a_2-a_3=0\}$

How to find the subspace formed by $W_1\cap W_2$, $W_1\cap W_3$ and $W_2\cap W_3$?

Thanks...:)

Comment: Do you know what each subspace defines geometrically?

Comment: First one is a line, while second and third are planes...

Comment: Perfect, so what do you think the intersection of a plane and a line will give you?

Comment: @Ritu Just solve the three equations and see what you get.

Comment: @Mattos It may give a point or a line, generally a line...

Comment: @zed111 I think I am getting zero subspace for intersection of all three, but I am not sure...

Comment: You have a system of three equations which may have a unique solution, no solution or infinite no. of solutions. I'm sure you can solve the system and describe the intersection

Comment: @Ritu Certainly the intersection of two planes and a line (all through the origin) in $\Bbb R^3$ is generically trivial. It is only a line if the line subspace is contained in both planes, and this clearly a very special arrangement.

Comment: @Travis Please go through my edit, is my solution correct?

Comment: @Ritu Plugging $W_1$ into $W_2$, we get $2(3a_2)-7a_2-a_2=-2a_2=0 \implies a_2=0$. Not what you are claiming

Comment: @zed111 Thank you for pointing out. Are the conclusions okay now?

Comment: Your matrix with top row 1, 4, -1: shouldn't that be 1, -4, -1?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right. It's a typo, the calculation is right..

Comment: @Ritu I only saw your message now, but it looks like everything has been resolved favorably! I encourage you to post an answer to your question and move your solution there.

Comment: @Ritu seems right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we put $a_1=3a_2$, $a_2=a_2$ and $a_3=-a_2$ in $2a_1-7a_2+a_3=0$, then $a_2=0$. Therefore, $\{0\}$ is the subspace formed by $W_1 \cap W_2$.

If we put $a_1=3a_2$, $a_2=a_2$ and $a_3=-a_2$ in $a_1-4a_2-a_3=0$; the equation is satisfied. So, I conclude $W_1 \subset W_3$. That is, $W_1$ is the subspace formed by $W_1\cap W_3$.

For finding subspace formed by $W_2\cap W_3$, the matrix $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -4 & -1\\ 2 & -7 & 1 \\ \end{array} } \right]$ can be row reduced to $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -4 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 3 \\ \end{array} } \right]$. Therefore, $W_2\cap W_3 = \{(-11a_3,-3a_3,a_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid a_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ .